# Is there a best practices for INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a table out of a other table with INTO. Now I want insert data into it. Is it best practices to name all the columns in the INSERT clause?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail_2]

INSERT INTO [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail_2]
    SELECT
        b.Name,
        b.ProductNumber,
        a.[DueDate],
        a.[OrderQty],
        a.[ProductID],
        a.[UnitPrice],
        a.[LineTotal],
        a.[ReceivedQty],
        a.[RejectedQty],
        a.[StockedQty],
        a.[ModifiedDate]
    FROM 
        [AdventureWorks2019].[Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail] AS a
    INNER JOIN 
        Production.Product AS b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID


SELECT * 
FROM [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail_2]
```

Comment: `Is it best practices to name all the columns in the INSERT clause?`:  Good day, In my onion it is a must! so the answer is YES

Comment: **Yes** - definitely! You should always specify all columns in your `INSERT` statement to avoid any nasty surprises when the order of columns might suddenly change in your table....

Comment: Yes! Why would it be a good practice to _not_ name them? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that True. but you have to write your column names in insert command, For examlpe:

INSERT INTO [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail_2] (x, y , z,...)
SELECT
b.Name,
b.ProductNumber,
a.[DueDate],
a.[OrderQty],
a.[ProductID],
a.[UnitPrice],
a.[LineTotal],
a.[ReceivedQty],
a.[RejectedQty],
a.[StockedQty],
a.[ModifiedDate]
FROM
[AdventureWorks2019].[Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail] AS a
INNER JOIN
Production.Product AS b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID

Comment: why? why its important it works without too